# Multiplying data within columns python

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I've been working on this all morning and for the life of me cannot figure it out. I'm sure this is very basic, but I've become so frustrated my mind is being clouded. I'm attempting to calculate the total return of a portfolio of securities at each date (monthly).

The formula is (1 + r1) * (1+r2) * (1+ r(t))..... - 1

Here is what I'm working with:

```
Adj_Returns = Adj_Close/Adj_Close.shift(1)-1
Adj_Returns['Risk Parity Portfolio'] = (Adj_Returns.loc['2003-01-31':]*Weights.shift(1)).sum(axis = 1) 

Adj_Returns

               SPY         IYR        LQD       Risk Parity Portfolio
Date                
2002-12-31      NaN       NaN         NaN       0.000000
2003-01-31  -0.019802  -0.014723    0.000774   -0.006840
2003-02-28  -0.013479   0.019342    0.015533    0.011701
2003-03-31  -0.001885   0.010015    0.001564    0.003556
2003-04-30  0.088985    0.045647    0.020696    0.036997
```

For example, with 2002-12-31 being base 100 for risk parity, I want 2003-01-31 to be 99.316 (100 * (1-0.006840)), 2003-02-28 to be 100.478 (99.316 * (1+ 0.011701)) so on and so forth.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`pd.DataFrame.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html)

```
df.add(1).cumprod().sub(1).sum(1)
```

---

Consider the dataframe of returns `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(.025, .03, (10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df

          A         B         C         D         E
0 -0.038892 -0.013054 -0.034115 -0.042772  0.014521
1  0.024191  0.034487  0.035463  0.046461  0.048123
2  0.006754  0.035572  0.014424  0.012524 -0.002347
3  0.020724  0.047405 -0.020125  0.043341  0.037007
4 -0.003783  0.069827  0.014605 -0.019147  0.056897
5  0.056890  0.042756  0.033886  0.001758  0.049944
6  0.069609  0.032687 -0.001997  0.036253  0.009415
7  0.026503  0.053499 -0.006013  0.053447  0.047013
8  0.062084  0.029664 -0.015238  0.029886  0.062748
9  0.048341  0.065248 -0.024081  0.019139  0.028955
```

We can see the cumulative return or total return is

```
df.add(1).cumprod().sub(1)

          A         B         C         D         E
0 -0.038892 -0.013054 -0.034115 -0.042772  0.014521
1 -0.015641  0.020983  0.000139  0.001702  0.063343
2 -0.008993  0.057301  0.014565  0.014247  0.060847
3  0.011544  0.107423 -0.005853  0.058206  0.100105
4  0.007717  0.184750  0.008666  0.037944  0.162699
5  0.065046  0.235405  0.042847  0.039769  0.220768
6  0.139183  0.275786  0.040764  0.077464  0.232261
7  0.169375  0.344039  0.034505  0.135051  0.290194
8  0.241974  0.383909  0.018742  0.168973  0.371151
9  0.302013  0.474207 -0.005791  0.191346  0.410852
```

Plot it

```
df.add(1).cumprod().sub(1).plot()
```

[image]

Add sum of returns to new column

```
df.assign(Portfolio=df.add(1).cumprod().sub(1).sum(1))

          A         B         C         D         E  Portfolio
0 -0.038892 -0.013054 -0.034115 -0.042772  0.014521  -0.114311
1  0.024191  0.034487  0.035463  0.046461  0.048123   0.070526
2  0.006754  0.035572  0.014424  0.012524 -0.002347   0.137967
3  0.020724  0.047405 -0.020125  0.043341  0.037007   0.271425
4 -0.003783  0.069827  0.014605 -0.019147  0.056897   0.401777
5  0.056890  0.042756  0.033886  0.001758  0.049944   0.603835
6  0.069609  0.032687 -0.001997  0.036253  0.009415   0.765459
7  0.026503  0.053499 -0.006013  0.053447  0.047013   0.973165
8  0.062084  0.029664 -0.015238  0.029886  0.062748   1.184749
9  0.048341  0.065248 -0.024081  0.019139  0.028955   1.372626
```